# Google Maps API v3: Opening the link on a marker in a new window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

seems like a pretty basic thing, but I don't seem to be finding the answer.
Here's my Google Maps code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(123, 123),
      url: "http://www.google.com",
      map: map
    });
```

...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = marker.url;
});
```

What do I need to change, to open the link in a new window?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the method `open` of the `window` object like this:

`window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");`

So your code will be something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.open(marker.url);
});
```

Visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for an overview of the `open` method and the options you can set.

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly fine!

Comment: but when i click, the maps lose their marker... why?

Comment: @Miguel isn't normal. Post your code for further details.

Comment: I mean when i click on the "google symbol" it goes to the area, but the marker position aka Icon, is not there.

Answer (score 1):

So I used this approach but when I was in a loop making lots of markers, each with a different URL, this was the approach I needed to take.

```
    var newLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(row[0], row[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: newLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: row[2],
        url: row[3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+this.url);
    });
```

Note that the key was using `this.url` in the listener code. If I used `marker.url` in the listener code, it would open the last of many urls for all of the markers.